# MySQL error after updating on

Tags: mysql

Here i am trying to insert into **payment_table after updating the review_table** *only after the status in review_table is updated to 2* .But there is error after running this trigger i.e,

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the

Trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER payment_details_trig AFTER UPDATE ON review_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF NEW.status=2
  INSERT INTO payment_table(paper_id, payment_mode, payment_refNo, payment_image,status)
  VALUES (0,0,0,0,0);
 END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing sticks out except for the missing `THEN`.  You might need delimiter statements:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER payment_details_trig AFTER UPDATE ON review_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.status = 2 THEN
            INSERT INTO payment_table(paper_id, payment_mode, payment_refNo, payment_image,status)
                VALUES (0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue `1064` in `SQL` comes in following four cases:

1) **Use of reserved words**:

Every version of `MySQL` has its own list of `reserved words`. These are words that are used for specific purposes or perform specific functions within the `MySQL` engine. If you attempt to use one of these `reserved words`, you will receive the 1064 error.To fix the issue, you will want to surround the word with backticks “`”.

2) **Missing Data**:
Sometimes data in the database is missing. This can cause issues when this data is required for a query.

3) **Mistyped or missing Commands**:
One of the most common causes for the 1064 error is when a `SQL` statement uses a mistyped or missing command.

4) **Deprecated Commands**:
Some commands that were `deprecated` (slated for removal but still allowed for a period of time) eventually go obsolete. This means that the command is no longer valid in the `SQL` statement.

In your case third option is the answer is the reason of your error. You have missed writing `THEN` after `IF`.